# How to change status bar icons color in Android?

Tags: java, android, colors, icons, statusbar

I want to change the color of the status bar icon from white to my own custom color so that it works in all versions. I try the following code but I can not do it. could you help me, please?

---

The code I used, but this code is not the only solution for APIS + 23 and doesn't work for low API (API 16, API 17 and etc ).

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
```

[image]

The color scheme I want to change.

```
color #5DD6D6
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I'm aware you cannot tint status bar icons on android. You can either make your them white or dark (light status bar).

Comment: status bar ican can either be grey or white depending on theme

Comment: Whatever I did, I could not adjust my desired color

Comment: I make the color gray. BUT doesn't work in lower APIs ANDROID

Comment: Do you have a good method for low API that I can use more easily?

Comment: I am afraid that its not possible to customize the color of the status bar icons.

Comment: So how do you think I can change the default from white to black so that fewer don't problems occur in lower Android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't actually change the status bar icon color in android like that. You can still change the status bar color to whatever you want, but for status bar icons, there are only 2 options - Light (white) or Dark (gray).

If you want to use white icons, then simply put `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>` attribute in your base application theme. For dark icons `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>`

You can also do it programmatically like mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39596725/10357086

Comment: Yes I did , but i can't stable for lower APIs.

Answer (score 0):

in kotlin you can use following lines

```java
// for white color of status bar 
       
 val window = this.window
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView).apply {
            isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
        }


// for other color of status bar  

val window = this.window
  window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
    window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.other_color)
    WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView).apply {
        isAppearanceLightStatusBars = false
    }
```