# How to change status bar default text color in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to change the status bar default text color in Android - Jetpack composes, Change the status bar text color from White to Black (Time, Wifi and network icon, etc...)

[image]

Comment: You should look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672833/android-m-light-and-dark-status-bar-programmatically-how-to-make-it-dark-again/39596725#39596725

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
setContent {
        MyTheme {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
                val useDarkIcons = !isSystemInDarkTheme()

                SideEffect {
                    systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(
                        color = Color(0xff655D8A),
                        darkIcons = !useDarkIcons
                    )
                }
              }
            }
```

Basically, use dark icons if system is not in dark theme.

Another possibility is to get the luminance of your status bar.

```
 fun isDark(color: Int): Boolean {
            return ColorUtils.calculateLuminance(color) < 0.5
        }
```

And use it like this for example:

```
fun getTextColor(accentColor: Int): Color {
            val color =
                if (isDark(accentColor)) {
                    Color.White
                } else {
                    Color.DarkGray
                }
            return color
        }
```